# .NET MVC site loads as plain text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I had to rebuild a .net mvc application in visual studio 2015, it was previously in 2010. After getting the site to build, when I 1st visit it, it loads as plain text, showing the html, until I hit refresh, then it loads properly. How do I resolve this?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.c]om/LlGUQ.png

Comment: Could be a cache issue. Try a hard reload (CTRL + R in chrome) to completely clear the cache and load the page from scratch.

Comment: Here are some things to try:  run it using F5 instead of ctrl + F5, run it in Incognito mode, kill your IIS Express instance and rerun.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but this happens on the initial load of the site after each build. It will load after I hit F5. I of course have tried all the basics like recycling the app pool, iisreset, rebooting the server, etc. I'm 90% sure that it's something that I missed while rebuilding the solution in VS2015.

Comment: Also of note, there are no errors in the browser console or in the Event Viewer.